# how to make unique intent, entity type and entity value?

Tags: php, dialogflow-es

need some help. below is the code which i have done (webhook) to take value from api.ai and grab the answer from a database. But now i m have problem as if two user enter the chatbot, the webhook do not know which user is asking about what. Means it is getting confuse so how do i have each intent, entity type and entity value unique for each user so that the webhook will not get confuse.

```
<?php

$databaseHost = 'localhost';
$databaseName = 'dialog';
$databaseUsername = 'root';
$databasePassword = '';
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($databaseHost, $databaseUsername, $databasePassword, $databaseName);


header('Content-Type: application/json');
ob_start();
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json, true);

$sessionID = $data["sessionId"]; //session id by API
$intent = $data["result"]["metadata"]["intentName"]; //intent

foreach($data["result"]["parameters"] as $key => $value) {
  if($value){
    $type = $key; //entity type
    $value = $value; //entity value
  }
}


$array = array();
foreach ($sessionID as $arr) {
  if(in_array($arr, $array)){

  }
  else {
    $array = array("id"=>$arr, "type"=>$type, "value"=>$value);
  }
}


$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM dialog");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
  if($row["eType"] == $type && $row["eVal"] == $value && $row["intent"] == $intent)
  {
    $outputtext = $row["reply"];
  }
}


$output["speech"] = $outputtext;
$output["displayText"] = $outputtext;

ob_end_clean();
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by asking username/name. In intent, add a required parameter.
There is a sample at https://api.ai/docs/getting-started/basic-fulfillment-conversation#conversation_branching